# Use embedded signing facility in an iframe

Tags: docusignapi

This is regarding docusignapi.

Is there a possibility to use the embedded signing facility in an iframe ?

My requirement is, give the signing facility from my application itself without redirecting to another webpage ? (At least that user behavior)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do that. You get back a url from calling the POST to receive an embedded signing session. You can embed this url in an iframe in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

If you do use an iFrame for an embedded signing ceremony, then be sure to set the iFrame dimensions to 100% by 100%. This is needed so that the signing ceremony user experience will be correct for the signer, especially on mobile devices.

If you want to personalize the signing ceremony (colors, logo, etc), you can do so via the DocuSign Branding feature.